# How to assemble Tensorflow Model with residual connections based on other model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to get the recipe for a model that contains residual connections and I want to change dimensions of some layers (thus, I barely can use tf.keras.clone_model() method) to re-assemble this model. How to do it?

I have tried to read all the residual connections:

```
non_seq_layers = {layer.name: l[0].name for layer in model.layers if isinstance(l:=layer._inbound_nodes[0].inbound_layers, list) and l}
```

l[1] is always just previous layer, l[0] shows residual connection (Resnet50).

Then I tried to assemble model (without any shape modifications):

```
def recompose(model, non_seq_layers):
    new_model = Model()
    previous_layer = model.input
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer = copy_layer(layer)
        if layer.name in non_seq_layers:
            previous_layer = layer([previous_layer, model.get_layer(non_seq_layers[layer.name]).output])
        else:
            previous_layer = layer(previous_layer)
        
        
    new_model = Model(model.input, previous_layer)
    return new_model
```

Everything works fine untill I the `conv3_block1_add` layer (Resnet50) where I got error:

```
ValueError: Inputs have incompatible shapes. Received shapes (14, 14, 512) and (28, 28, 512)
```

Is it a proper way to manage such task? How to repair it? Perhaps sth with encoding residual connections (`non`*`seq`*`layers` ) may be wrong.